# OpenGL: Major opcode of failed request: 150 (GLX)

Tags: opengl, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-18.04, x11, glx

win10 + wsl1 (ubuntu18.04)

I want to  install opengl, here are my steps:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev  libglu1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
sudo apt-get install libglew-dev libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libglm-dev libfreetype6-dev libglfw3-dev libglfw3
```

but when i ran "glxinfo | grep OpenGL", i got the following results, why?

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  150 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  35 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  21
  Current serial number in output stream:  41
```

Other information: i install VcXsrv in win10(click "Native opengl"). After installation, open "~/.bashrc", set "export DISPLAY=:0.0".